# How would you monitor how much time has passed when the user is not on the site? (Laravel/PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, events, timer

Consider the following example:

User click a button, the button sends some kind of request back to start a task that completes after 30 minutes. On the front end, we show a timer counting down the 30 minutes.

If the user stays for thirty minutes, then something else happens. If the user leaves, logs out or closes the browser, the timer should still be running, but this time on the back end.

I know in this case I would use Laravel's Event/notification system to handle the whole button is clicked, lets set up the timer and notify when done. But how do I monitor that ok X happened while you were gone and when you log back in or come back (after 30 minutes) theres a notification

Essentially how do you replicate "those games" that have timers and allow you to leave and come back and the timer (over real world time) has gone down?

Comment: You set a start time and duration or start and end time in a database or other persistent store, and then use those rather than any kind of actual timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using `Middleware` in conjunction with the database.

Create `Middleware` for tracking the user's activity, and **apply it to routes** that you want to track the user on:

```
class TouchOnline
{
    /**
     * The user
     *
     * @var $user
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Create a new session middleware
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = Auth::user();
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Update their timestamp
        if (count($this->user)) $this->user->touchOnline();

        // Continue with request
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

In your `User` model you will need:

- A method to update their last_active attribute
- A method to set their time_limit attribute
- A method to compare the two

Which might look something like:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * Update a user's last_active time
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function touchOnline()
    {
        $this->last_active = $this->freshTimestamp();
        $this->save();
    }

    /**
     * Set a user's time_limit
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function setTimeLimit()
    {
        $this->time_limit = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(30);
        $this->save();
    }

    /**
     * Sort if user has lapsed over time_limit
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isUserOverTimeLimit()
    {
        $last_active = $this->last_active;
        $time_limit = $this->time_limit;

        if ($last_active > $time_limit) return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Done roughly but should point you in the correct direction. Hope it helps!